# PowerBI AADSTS90002: Tenant authorize not found

Tags: c#, powerbi-embedded

**Reference:** [Power BI Sample Solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples)

I have moved the necessary code from the sample solution to my solution and its giving me the following error when authenticating:

> AADSTS90002: Tenant authorize not found. This may happen if there are
> no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription
> administrator.

I am authenticating with these 2 lines:

```
 var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
 var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ApplicationId, credential);
```

The error is occurring on the last line. Below are values in my web.config:

```
<add key="authorityUrl" value="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/" />
<add key="resourceUrl" value="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" />
```

Again, this works 100% in the sample app but not when I move to my app. Any ideas why ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So after some research I found that it was to do with the version of the following nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
Microsoft.PowerBI.Api
```

The following versions needed to be used:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.13.9
Microsoft.PowerBI.Api V2.0.12
```

It seems it has something to do with the endpoints that are used. If you downgrade to the above versions(which are the same versions used in the sample tool provided), then it works.

The latest versions use something like this : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/` where the versions provided in the same uses : `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/`

Once I "downgraded" my versions, it authenticated!

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  Downgrading did the trick for me.  First, though, I had to create a new ActiveDirectory and app, like the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/create-an-azure-active-directory-tenant.  Then, I had to register the app, like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app.  Finally, I had to create a secret for the app in Azure Portal by selecting the app and creating a secret.

Comment: Pleasure. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 20):

In my case instead of downgrading `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`, I changed the authentication endpoint from `https://login.windows.net/{My tenant}/oauth2/token`to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{My tenant}` which resolved the issue.

Comment: I had to change mine to `https://login.windows.net/common/` but it works just the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes all the answer are correct, I just want to put some lights on the things like why it's working in low version and not in new version

As per the [official doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Changes-adalnet-4.0#better-authority-validation) this is a **better authority validation update from microsoft**

> ADAL.NET 4.x is also less forgiving than ADAL 3.x when setting the
>   authority in the constructor of AuthenticationContext. Valid
>   authorities should be, in the case of Azure AD v1.0:
>
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Guid}, where the Guid is the    tenant ID
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/domainName, where the    domain    name is a domain associated with your tenant
> - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common which, in the case of    ADAL.NET means any Azure AD tenant (note that the meaning is
>     different in MSAL.NET)
>
>   It cannot be https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/OAuth2/endpoint
>     even if this for could have been wrongly accepted in ADAL 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by reverting the assembly "**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory**" to Version=3.13.9.1126.

Using latest version of this assembly raised this issue. Version = 4.4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The fix is quite simple but it's hard to find it from Microsoft Docs as they are very vast. So I'm sharing what worked for us.

Note that we are using `AuthenticationContext` combined with `ClientCredential` to get the token.

The AuthorityUrl for `3.x` versions is - `https://login.windows.net/{yourOrg}/oauth2/token`

After upgrading to `4.x` or later it should be changed to - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourOrg}`

Incase if you are wondering the full code is just 2 lines

```cs
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AppSettings.AuthorityUri);
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AppSettings.ResourceUri, new ClientCredential(AppSettings.ClientId, AppSettings.ClientSecret)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```