# Error : Tenant authorize not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, adal, dynamics-365

I have written the following code to acquire token for CRM.

```
class Program
{
    private const string username = "richa@azuretraining112.onmicrosoft.com";
    private const string password = "Pa$$w0rd";
    private const string serviceURL = "https://azuretraining112.crm8.dynamics.com";
    private const string applicationID = "89a70b76-3a71-481f-8755-a7aa97c59c35";
    private const string redirectURL = "https://localhost1";
    private const string authorityURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/1d54ea41-cd25-488f-812c-c078e6114065/oauth2/authorize";
    private static AuthenticationResult authResult = null;


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityURI);
        authResult = context.AcquireTokenAsync(serviceURL, applicationID, credentials).Result;
    }
}
```

But, while running the code, I am getting the following error while trying to get the token using AcquireTokenAsync.

> [image: Blockquote]

I have added an application user using the application ID : 
[image]

I don't know what I am missing. Please help!

I tried with the solution given in [Tenant not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645374/error-aadsts90002-on-aquire-authentication-token-for-dynamics-365), but, nothing worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error AADSTS90002 on aquire authentication token for Dynamics 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645374/error-aadsts90002-on-aquire-authentication-token-for-dynamics-365)

Comment: @ArunVinoth, I tried both the methods mentioned in the given link. None of that seems to work.

Comment: Did you try removing “oauth2/authorize” in uri. Discussion going on between endpoint & authority confusion: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19593

Comment: I am getting the following : The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502733/powerbi-aadsts90002-tenant-authorize-not-found/53517438#53517438 i think this ans may help you

Answer (score 0):

configure this url with port number "https://localhost1:5000" and configure the same "https://localhost1:5000" in reply URL of Azure AD.

Let me know if this works